# Use NGinx reverse proxy for create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to create a ReactJS app on a remote Ubuntu server. In order to test it in the browser I'm using the NGinx reverse-proxy features as this.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mentalg.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://172.31.23.249:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /client/ {
                proxy_pass http://172.31.23.249:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

the 5000 port is for the REST `/api` end-points, all good here.

But the 3000 port on which the development react server runs creates issues.

The site opens as needed at `http://mentalg.com/client`, but inside the `index.html` there is a url for the script file to be executed as 
`static/js/bundle.js` file. This file is served by the React dev server normally but NGinx won't see it.

The url `static/js/bundle.js` is generated on the fly by the `create-react-app` dev server, can't control it.

How do I modify further the nginx proxy to server the files from `static` folder correctly?

Comment: It could perhaps be possible to solve it with a rewrite? I have the same problem but I'm not exactly certain how.

Answer (score 8):

Adding these 2 rules, solved the initial problem.

```
location /static/ {
        proxy_pass http://172.31.23.249:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_pass http://172.31.23.249:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why here your domain ip instead of localhost (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: guess it was copy/pasted code, localhost would work as well

Comment: This is a very ugly solution and wont work with multiple react servers. Is there no better solution yet?

Comment: I'd love to see it as well. One day, maybe ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and found a way to solve it by using a combination of rewrite and setting the homepage option in create-react-apps package.json.

In `package.json` you add

```
"homepage": "http://172.31.23.249/client"
```

This will make the generated url in `index.html` to be generates a `/client/static/js/...` so it will reach the right redirect directive for nginx.

Once it reaches the redirect from nginx we need to remove the leading `/client` before passing it on to the proxy, which we can do with a rewrite directive.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mentalg.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://172.31.23.249:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /client/ {
                rewrite ^/client(/.*)$ $1 break;

                proxy_pass http://172.31.23.249:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

I have this setup with several react apps served on the same host in this way, and it's working nicely.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `homepage` is only honored by the webpack build script, not the webpack start script. The webpack development server still returns an `index.html` that contains relative URLs like `/static/main.js` and not `/client/static/main.js`. What am I missing?

Comment: @jdolan You're not missing anything. The question is about how to deploy the app behind an NGINX server. On the development server you can use the [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) field instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   root /[file_root_directory];
   server_name [hostname];
   index index.html index.htm;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:[PORT]
   }
}
```